# Reschedule Celery task from inside same task

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I want to simulate a cron-type task, by scheduling the same task from inside a task. Something along these lines:

```
@task
def my_task():
    # do some heavy stuff here, but paginated [:10]
    my_task.delay()
```

Is this possible? Is it good practice to do this?

Comment: If you want cron features, why don't you use [Celery Beat](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)?

Comment: Because I'm not sure how long each task takes to run, and I need it to run sequentially (because I'm too lazy to implement thread-safety). Does Celery Beat offer something like this? I already went through some of the docs but haven't found anything.